# Servlet URL mapping creating problem

Tags: servlets, mapping

I'm unable to identify the problem, I've the following URL Pattern for opening the report servlet,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ReportFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web.servlet.ReportFile</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ReportFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlets/ReportFile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

which is working if I open it directly under context that is if I open it as: context/ReportFile, it works, but when I write context/Servlets/ReportFile, It says page not found? What can be the issue? I just want to define URL so that I can apply security on that URL pattern. Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you rebuild/redeploy/restart the webapp/server after change in web.xml?

Comment: That was a silly mistake of other programmer :( it's working now! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following mapping in my application and it worked perfectly fine on tomcat:

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>search</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/Servlets/search/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Have you tried adding the trailing /* ?